# Azure Storage Blob: set CORS on the blobs level?

Tags: azure, cors, azure-blob-storage

Currently, we have set CORS for the whole container with:

```
azure storage cors set --blob static --cors '[{"AllowedOrigins":"*","AllowedMethods":"GET","MaxAgeInSeconds":"86400"}]'
```

Is there any possibility to set rule directly and separately for each `blob` in that container?

E.g. - for `static/images/pic.png` set `"AllowedOrigins":"*"` but for `static/css/style.css` - set `"AllowedOrigins":"google.com"`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there any possibility to set rule directly and separately for each
>   blob in that container?

Unfortunately no. The way I understand `CORS` is that it somehow enables trust between 2 domains. With Azure Storage, the domains are by service (e.g. `youraccount.blob.core.windows.net` etc.). Thus the CORS rules are set at the service level.