# Azure AD B2C - how to implement custom sign up process?

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api, asp.net-core-2.0

This is basically a follow up to my prev question - https://stackoverflow.com/a/44738654/2896495. I've implemented an Azure B2C sign up and auth in my web app (.NET Core 2.0) and now I want to add a custom sign up logic with Graph API (as described here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-graph-dotnet).
But I'm confused about app registrations. For B2C auth I created an app in the Portal under Azure AD B2C -> Applications. Now, in order to use custom sign up logic I need another app registration under Portal -> App Registrations -> New Application Registration (where I can grant necessary permissions to Azure AD, like Read and Write directory data).

So, if I need auth AND custom sigh up, how should I set up my app? What's the right way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are just trying to have your own look and feel, as opposed to the default templates with your logos and other branding, then look into providing a template for UI customizations:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-ui-customization

Also, see this other answer to a similar question:

[Azure AD B2C UI Customization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45428978/azure-ad-b2c-ui-customization/45467170#45467170)

If you are trying for a whole different workflow, the you will want to create a custom policy.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-overview-custom

Or if that does not work, then I guess you could just use the GraphApi, but that is the most laborious of options and completely destroys the entire purpose of using B2C in the first place. I do not recommend this approach.

**Update:**

I would not do everything you want to do in a custom policy. Separating the signup into it's own application/service would be a great approach (as @camsoper suggested), but only use the policies for the bare amount needed to create the initial account or authenticate an approved user. I've never used a policy to change the "accountActive" attribute, but I would be inclined to use the GraphApi to modify the user profile after the account is created by using the "NewAccount" attribute to key off. There is a "Block sign in" setting on a users profile in the azure portal which can be used to restrict access (and the signup application could set the default after the account is created), but I'm not sure if that corresponds to the "accountActive" attribute or not (yet).

Most of the administration you've described can be done in the azure portal, such as changing the "Block sign in" setting on a users profile can be used to restrict access (and the signup application could set the default after the account is created). If there is some capability that the portal does not offer, I would put that into a separate application. Avoid duplicating functionality in your customized admin app, and instead just redirect the admin to the users profile in "portal.azure.com".

```
https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_AAD_IAM/UserDetailsMenuBlade/Profile/userId/{objectId}
```

Note: there may be some issues with that URL template if the admin has access to more than one Directory for her account. It will try to pull up the directory that her account was created on by default.

Comment: I want to have control over `accountEnabled` attribute, so new registrations are then approved by admin. Besides, I will need custom attributes and I will need the UI in my app to add/remove users from groups. Will custom policies allow me to cover all that?

Comment: @alvipeo I would not use custom policies to do what you are asking. See the edit for a more complete explanation.

Comment: ok, I actually created a lib which uses Graph API to create new users and change attributes when needed (I also use extension properties for custom user attributes). Now I'm going to create my own sign up page and just use Web API where I'd use that my lib. I don't see any disadvantages in this, but who knows... Do you have any suggestions to this maybe?

Answer (score 2):

For simplicity's sake, as well as a healthy separation of concerns, I would indeed make a separate app for the custom sign-up.  It doesn't have to be a full-fledged app, a microservice that does the sign-ups for the main B2C app would be fine.

Comment: Never heard using a separate app to manage users. This is just a web app, why keep them separated? It's just I can't find a good explanation on both Azure AD B2C and Graph API for ASP.NET Core 2.0

Comment: Well, to be fair, I was spitballing.  :)

Comment: @alvipeo Cam may have been spitballing, but that is exactly how I would prefer to design the application. B2C is supposed to be an SSO solution. You applications will be more flexible if you take full advantage of that.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use the [custom attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-custom-attr) to implement the custom sign up process, you need to register two apps as the document you mentioned in the post. One app is for integrating with Azure AD B2C for login, and the other is using the Azure AD Graph to query the custom attribute.

After that, you can using the Azure AD Graph REST to query the relative info and handle your own business logic in the web app. And to query the extension info, we just need to query the user info like below:

[image]

Comment: @alvipeo You should note that the custom attributes are not available until at least one user has been created through a policy with a value set for those attributes (unless they've fixed that?).