# Shared Azure blob image is not getting rendered properly on LinkedIn

Tags: linkedin-api, social-networking, azure-blob-storage, hello.js

Problem: I am using Hello.js hello.api() to share image and text based content. 
It shares as per provided values and it shares images which are uploaded on public domain. I am using Public azure container for image sharing, when I am sharing Azure based blob (jpg/png image) using same procedure the image reduces in size as comes next to the URL content as shown below.

[image]

Expected Behavior: Description text, then shared azure blob based image and after that URL which was shared with content should come as shown in expected behavior.

expected behavior:

[image: expected behavior]

Question:
Even when the blob is public and can be accessed from any user on any browser with actual dimensions, why LinkedIn is not rendering that image after post is shared. As per the guidelines image is within the image sharing limit.

Image dimensions:

Width 1600 px

Height 300 px

Comment: You may need to enable CORS for Blob service for retrieving image from browser-side. About how to do that, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28894466/how-can-i-set-cors-in-azure-blob-storage-in-portal/41351674#41351674).

Comment: Thanks @AaronChen ,I tried CORS as per the post however, it did not solve the problem. I will try to look more into this issue, will reach out to this page with more scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

Ashish,

Do you have content-type set for your blobs? If you don't set that then the blob may not be treated as an image by browsers.

Also, if nothing works you can always create a dummy page on your website that hosts that image and then share a link to that page.