# How to set CORS for Azure Blob Service for Premium Storage Account in the Azure Portal?

Tags: azure, cors, azure-blob-storage

I created a Premium `Azure Blob Storage` account, created a `Shared Access Signature` and tried to upload an image from a `asp.net core` web application html page that runs under `http://localhost:5001`.

I don't see a CORS section in the portal. So, I set **All Networks** under **Firewalls and virtual networks** which I think should allow `http://localhost:5001`.

I get the following error when I try to post to the **Blob** account:

`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://mypictures.blob.core.windows.net/<Token>' from origin 'https://localhost:5001' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

Comment: The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28894466/how-can-i-set-cors-in-azure-blob-storage-in-portal) says there is a **CORS** section under the **BLOB SERVICE** in the portal. But I don't see that in my portal account.

Comment: Quick question: Why are you creating a "Premium Storage Account" if you want to upload images?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you're getting this error is because CORS is not configured for the blob service for your storage account. The reason you don't see the option to configure CORS in Azure Portal is because CORS is not supported for `Premium Storage Accounts`.

From this [`link`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/cross-origin-resource-sharing--cors--support-for-the-azure-storage-services):

[image]

You will need to upload a file in a premium storage account using other ways like `AzCopy`, `Azure PowerShell`, `Azure CLI`, any storage explorer or write code yourself using any available SDK.

Comment: I upload the files to the non-premium Blob storage using the angular package ```@azure/storage-blob``` now. I can upload it from the browser directly. Even if I can use SDK calls inside a **Asp.net core Web API**, will the **Premium Blob Storage** allow the requests from another **app service** endpoint which hosts the **Asp.net core Web API**?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Would you mind elaborating more? However if you wish to upload just image files (i.e. block blob) and want Premium performance, I would suggest choosing account kind as `BlockBlobStorage`. Account kinds of type `Storage` and `StorageV2` with `Premium` performance level only supports `Page` blobs which are for storing VHDs for your Virtual Machines.